# Something of that kind/ that kind of something

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Can I use these versions interchangeably?

> 1- I didn't say ***anything of that kind***.
>
> 2- I didn't say ***that kind of anything***.

---

> 3- It is ***a game of some kind***.
>
> 4- It is ***some kind of a game***.
>
> 5- It is ***some kind of game***.

Answer (score 0):

Number 1 is grammatically correct and idiomatic, but what would be more common, at least in U.S. English, is:

> I did not say anything of the kind.

Number 2 is not idiomatic, at least not in U.S. English. The phrase "that kind of " typically ends with a noun describing an identifiable class and means one or some, but not all, of the items in that class. "That kind of cat" distinguishes cats with some previously identified characteristic from cats in general. "Anything," however, does not refer to an identifiable class.

Numbers 3 and 5 are grammatical, idiomatic, and equivalent in meaning. Number 4 will certainly be understood, but does not sound idiomatic. "Some kind of" essentially acts as an indefinite article and thus renders "a" or "an" superfluous.

Comment: Thank you. I thought 4 and 5 was different. As far as I know, 5 refers to something that similiar to a game but it is not an actual game while 4 refers to a real game.

Comment: No. Number 4 does not sound idiomatic, but would be construed as having the same meaning as 3 and 5.

Comment: @TalhaÖzden Note that while 2. is not necessarily *idiomatic*, it's still actually *grammatical* (from a syntax point of view) and understandable. That still doesn't mean it's something you necessarily *should* say. Bu I do have to strongly disagree with the 4. being unidiomatic, however. I've heard it phrased that way often, and it seems natural to me. In fact, I'd almost say that the use of the article is *more* idiomatic than its omission.